# Why associatedtype protocol fails to compile with error: does not conform to protocol

Tags: swift

I try to compile Swift file with associated protocol and it fails to compile with error

```
import Foundation

protocol ViewProtocol {
}

protocol PresenterProtocol {
    associatedtype ViewType: ViewProtocol

    var view: ViewType {get}
}

protocol ExampleViewProtocol: ViewProtocol { 
}

class ExamplePresenter: PresenterProtocol {
    var view: ExampleViewProtocol

    init(view: ExampleViewProtocol) {
        self.view = view
    }
}
```

Error appears in Xcode 10.2 and XCode 10.1:

Type 'ExamplePresenter' does not conform to protocol 'PresenterProtocol'

I don't understand why. What should be done to make it compile?

Comment: See [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) – `ExampleViewProtocol` *inherits* from from `ViewProtocol`, but does not *conform* to it.

Comment: when you have an associated type, your `view` cannot be a protocol itself.  you need to use a concrete type. I'm running into the same problem with my Viper structure. I don't want to use a concrete type but I want the common code to reside in a base class.  I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: This also looks like a misuse of protocols. You likely meant Presenter to be a generic, not a protocol. What generic algorithm would make use of PresenterProtocol (keeping in mind that you cannot put these presenters in a variable or an array because this is a PAT)? Protocols are not abstract base classes (which it looks like you may also be treating them as here).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `ExampleViewProtocol` inherits from `ViewProtocol` instead of conforming to it. To make your code compile, you could try adapting `ExampleViewProtocol` to make it a class. This would make `ExampleViewProtocol` a concrete type which will allow it to conform to `ViewProtocol`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add generic type constraints to ExamplePresenter

```
class ExamplePresenter<T: ExampleViewProtocol>: PresenterProtocol {
    typealias ViewType = T

    var view: T

    init(view: T) {
        self.view = view
    }
}
```